# Press a button in ViewA and update tableview in viewB

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I want to dynamically assign a string url value in ViewA then press a button in ViewA and have ViewB tableview update with the text of the url from ViewA.

What is the best method to accomplish this without using storyboards?

Thanks

Comment: Lots of ways to do this, using properties, delegation, notification etc. Deciding which approach is best is upto you.

Comment: Why down vote and close this question?  Clearly this is a valid beginner programming question.  The OP can use Amar's comment and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, by viewA/viewB you mean viewControllerA / B (VCA / VCB)

Set a public property 'let said url' in VCB

in VCA, alloc/init a new VCB, set VCB.url, present VCB.

Did you need Objective-c code, or this pseudo code will be enough to start ?

Comment: Please consider to add your question as a comment.